# Varios ion-slides no funcionan en Ionic 4

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4, ionic-framework, angular8

Estoy creando una aplicación con tabs. En **tab2.page.html** tengo 2 , os dejo código para comprender mejor:

```
<ion-slides class="slidesTab2" #slidesTab2 pager="false">
    <ion-slide>
      ---- código ----
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
      ---- código ----
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>

--- código ---

<ion-col>
   <ion-button shape="round" size="small" fill="outline" color="tertiary (click)="goToNext()">
   Next
   </ion-button>
</ion-col>
   <ion-button shape="round" size="small" fill="outline" color="tertiary (click)="goToPrev()">
   Prev
   </ion-button>
</ion-col>
```

y su correspondiente clase **tab2.page.ts**:

```
@ViewChild('slidesTab2', { static: true }) slidesTab2: IonSlides;
 --- código ---

goToNext() {
   this.slidesTab2.lockSwipes( false );
   this.slidesTab2.slideNext();
   this.slidesTab2.lockSwipes( true );
}

goToPrev() {
   this.slidesTab2.lockSwipes( false );
   this.slidesTab2.slidePrev();
   this.slidesTab2.lockSwipes( true );
}
```

En **tab3.page.html** tengo otros 2 , os dejo código para comprender mejor:

```
<ion-slides class="slidesTab3" #slidesTab3 pager="false">
    <ion-slide>
      ---- código ----
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
      ---- código ----
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>

--- código ---

<ion-col>
   <ion-button shape="round" size="small" fill="outline" color="tertiary (click)="goToNext()">
   Next
   </ion-button>
</ion-col>
   <ion-button shape="round" size="small" fill="outline" color="tertiary (click)="goToPrev()">
   Prev
   </ion-button>
</ion-col>
```

y su correspondiente clase **tab3.page.ts**:

```
@ViewChild('slidesTab3', { static: true }) slidesTab3: IonSlides;
 --- código ---

goToNext() {
   this.slidesTab3.lockSwipes( false );
   this.slidesTab3.slideNext();
   this.slidesTab3.lockSwipes( true );
}

goToPrev() {
   this.slidesTab3.lockSwipes( false );
   this.slidesTab3.slidePrev();
   this.slidesTab3.lockSwipes( true );
}
```

El problema que solo funciona el primer slides que abro. Es decir, abro la aplicación, abro el tab2 y funciona perfectamente el slides. Y si seguidamente abro tab3, el slides declarado en esta clase no funciona. He probado a imprimir en cada función el index activo con **slide.getActiveIndex();**, pero el slides que abro en segundo lugar, el que no funciona, imprime empty. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo para que funcionen 2 slides? Gracias.

UPDATE:

También he probado con modificar la forma de cambiar de slide:

```
goToNext() {
   this.slidesTab2.lockSwipes( false );
   this.slidesTab2.slideTo(1);
   this.slidesTab2.lockSwipes( true );
}

goToPrev() {
   this.slidesTab2.lockSwipes( false );
   this.slidesTab2.slideTo(0);
   this.slidesTab2.lockSwipes( true );
}
```

UPDATE:

También he podido observar que después de unos minutos sin utilizar los slides, dejan de funcionar. He añadido console.log('Entra') y lo ejecuta, pero parece no ejecutar los métodos del slide (slideTo, SlidePrev, SlideNext).

Answer (score -1):

Para que funcione tienes que poner

```
this.slidesTab2.update()
```

y se actualiza el slider y vuelve a funcionar.